# A multi-step wizard form with multiple <ui:include>s and one request scoped bean, how to proceed to next step?

Tags: jsf-2

We are working with JSF 2.0. Actually, we are migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0.
I have a form on `mainPage.xhtml` wherein we include 3 forms by `<ui:include>` tag.

The `mainPage.xhtml` page look like below,

```
    <c:if test="#{myManagedBean.stepRender eq 'firstPage'}">
        <ui:include src="/public/firstPage.xhtml"/>
    </c:if> 
    <c:if test="#{myManagedBean.stepRender eq 'secondPage'}">
        <ui:include src="/public/secondPage.xhtml"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{myManagedBean.stepRender eq 'thirdPage'}">
        <ui:include src="/public/thirdPage.xhtml"/>
    </c:if>
```

The `firstPage.xhtml` has a few input fields and one `<h:commandButton>` with `action="myManagedBean.continueStepOne"`.

The `secondPage.xhtml` has a few input fields and one `<h:commandButton>` with `action="myManagedBean.continueStepTwo"`.

The `thirdPage.xhtml` has also a few input fields and one `<h:commandButton>` with `action="myManagedBean.continueStepThree"`.

I used only one bean for all included pages and `mainPage.xhtml` page. The bean is request scoped.

The code of the bean class

```
public String continueStepOneAction(){
    == validation logic ==
    stepRender="secondPage";
    return "mainPage";

}

public String continueStepTwoAction(){
    == validation logic ==
    stepRender="thirdPage";
    return "mainPage";

}
```

Initially when I send a request to `mainPage.xhtml`, depending on the `stepRender` value, it will include a particular page which is initially `firstPage.xhtml`.

If we enter data and click on commandbutton, then it will call `continueStepOne` action. When validations are successful, then `stepRender` value is changed. If it equals to `secondPage`, then `secondPage.xhtml` page will be included. And so on for the `thirdPage`.

The problem is, from `firstPage` to `secondPage` the method call and navigation are working properly, but in `secondPage`, when we click on the command button, then it will call only the constructor of `myManagedBean` and it is not calling the `continueStepThreeAction()` method in the bean. It will navigate to `firstPage.xhtml`, because in the `stepRender` value defaults to `firstPage`.

I am not able to understand where is the problem is. How can I solve it?

Comment: Cause is obvious: the `stepRender` is not retained in subsequent request. But I wonder, how did you implement it for JSF 1.x then?

Answer (score 0):

is your managed bean in request scope?, try it pushing to session scope by declaring it as session scoped bean.

Comment: but any problem with sessionScoped bean coming to security constraints? can you please explain

Comment: I dont know the scope of your app and importance of data you will be showing, if you are so concerned you must be having login/logout mechanism set up also session expiration fine tuned other than that I cannot think of any potential risks at this stage. What exactly do you have in your mind when you say 'security constraints'.

Comment: in our app we are accessing third party API to get the data. i think we cannot handle, if third party API is not implementing serialization interface when the bean scope is session scope.

Comment: If serialization is the concern you can declare those fields as transient and populate them back in hook methods provided by java writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) and readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) or define a proxy/wrapper for third party class which is serializable and you can handle data population, well all this is worth an effort in case session scoped bean solves your above problem.

Comment: and we dont have permissions to use bean scope as sessionscope.  Is there any other way to work my requirement properly.